# Trying to understand metaphorical meaning of 'intrusive'

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

My friend has reached out to me with following message:

> Please submit a request to resize the laptop hard disk. Let me know if
> this would be **intrusive** where we will communicate down time to the
> laptop owner.

I am not able to understand if this is correct use of the word **intrusive**. I am familiar with literal meaning of **intrusive** which is “tending to intrude (especially upon privacy)”.

### Underlying Message

> Please let me know if installing new hard disk will take more time so
> that we can communicate this to the customer.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly. Your friend ask you to submit a request (to a third party?) for a bigger/smaller hard disk in a lap top belonging to a 4th party?. Your friend seeks reassurance that either the request ? or the installation of the new disk? may pose a privacy risk? expose personal information? of the owner? It's not at all clear.

Comment: I have added more details to my question. thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it your friend had already made a preliminary estimate before they sent the laptop to you.

There is a clear indicator that they are concerned about the downtime (by the way that will likely impact costs also, anyways).

From this I take that they are inquiring whether the repairs are **more complex** than their original assessment, resulting in a more demanding procedure whose outcome is **harder to predict**, potentially needing additional efforts.

The metaphor here, I expect, is that a non-intrusive intervention is one whose progression is easier to predict, while an intrusive one may rapidly raise a series of exponentially severe challenges.

I believe this is very much analogous with the way this term is used in the field of health-care. In this case your friend seems to have used it in the context of technology. I wouldn't say it's invalid here; just uncommon.